# Expect script error send: spawn id exp4 not open while executing "send "password""

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, expect

I'm trying to run an expect script but I have an error:

```
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send "password"
```

My script is very simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!/usr/bin/env expect
#!/usr/bin/env export
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
spawn sftp -o IdentityFile=/home/localUser/MyPrivKeys_open.ppk user@123.123.123.123
expect "sftp.gatewayEnter passphrase for key '/home2/localUser/MyPrivKeys_open.ppk':"
send "passphrase\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /home/localUser/localPath \r"
expect "sftp>"
send "mget myfile.xml /home/localUser/localPath \r"
set timeout 5
interact
```

What I do is editing my expect script in notepad.exe but when i upload my script i have to run next commands:

dos2unix bash.sh -> converts dos file to a Unix file

chmod +x bash.sh -> gives execution permission

And finally i run my script:

./bash.sh

But after that it sends that error.
It is something really weird because i have another .sh file with the same structure and i am only changing paths where i get files

I think i need some help about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the sftp command is terminating before you get to the passphrase. Add `exp_internal 1` before the spawn command, see if the debugging output gives you any clues.

Comment: Glen, I have put your what you told me and result is:

parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {12374}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "sftp.gatewayEnter passphrase for key '/home2/localUser/MyPrivKeys_open.ppk':"? no
expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ""
send: sending "password\r" to { exp4 send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send "password\r""
    (file "./bash.sh" line 13)

What do you think about it?
Thanks man!

Comment: I see "read eof" there which indicates sftp has closed. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already fix it, it was an error in dos2unix command. I had to code it again over Ubuntu for avoiding to run dos2unix command.

Comment: can you please add more details?